Grandson traveling to Canada with grandparents
We will be traveling to Canada in a couple weeks with our 9 year old grandson for a week’s vacation. We have passports but he does not. What do we bring in lieu of a passport for him? Thanks!

Where are you traveling from, by what means, and what is your grandson's nationality?

He needs a passport.
In general children need passport. A parents passport where the child is included may be acceptable if the parent is travelling with the child, but that is not the case here.
You also should have a letter from the child's parents authorizing you to take him to Canada. The letter should include addresses and phone numbers for the parents. You should have copies of the parents passports.
See this official page.
The grandson may also need a visa, depending on nationality and other circumstances. If your grandson is American then other documents may suffice.

This depends on citizenship and mode of travel.
If your grandson is not a US citizen or a Canadian citizen

he needs a passport.

If you are flying to Canada

your grandson needs a passport.

If you are crossing the border by car...
(which I assume to be the case because of the "automobiles" tag)
... and your grandson is a US citizen

you may be able to make the trip with your grandson's birth certificate.

Canada has done their best to obscure this possibility, preferring instead to note that it is best to have a passport, so I can't find an official Canadian source saying explicitly that it is permissible.  But with only two weeks to go, your only other option is to apply for a passport urgently, in person, which costs a bit extra and may be considerably more inconvenient, depending on where you live.
Canada's page on Travel documents and identification requirements has links for entry requirements by country and for the Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada website.  The second is no help because it is a visa tool that assumes that you will be using a passport or one of several passport-like travel documents, which is not the case here.
The "entry requirements by country" page seems like it will be helpful, because it has a section for US citizens, but that section reads, in its entirety,

U.S. citizens must carry proper identification such as a valid U.S. passport.

But that link just takes you back to the original Travel documents and identification requirements page.  So there's no way to find out what other documents are acceptable.
[If you are crossing the border by car] and your grandson is a Canadian citizen

the situation is slightly better; see the Travel documents and identification requirements page, which includes a list of alternative documents, including citizenship, naturalization, and birth certificates, under the heading "Other acceptable documents for establishing Canadian citizenship."

Returning to the US
The US, by contrast, explicitly requires only proof of nationality for US and Canadian citizens under 16:

U.S. and Canadian citizen children under the age of 16 (or under 19, if traveling with a school, religious group, or other youth group) need only present a birth certificate or other proof of citizenship. The birth certificate can be original, photocopy, or certified copy.


"If your grandson is not a US citizen or a Canadian citizen ... he needs a passport." One exception would be if he was a US permanent resident, he would not need a passport. "If you are flying to Canada ... your grandson needs a passport." Technically, Canadian regulations does not require a passport for Canadian citizens or US citizens to enter Canada; I don't see anything in the regulations that differ for entry by air. The airline could require it by themselves, however.

"Returning to the US ... The US, by contrast, explicitly requires only proof of nationality for US and Canadian citizens under 16:" To clarify, this is only for entry to the US by land.
